# condition check in pandas dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe:

|  | date | open | high | low | close | volume | sma | sr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-29 | 22.5 | 22.5 | 22.5 | 22.5 | 5 | NaN | 1 |

Now I want to print the value of sma on if it's not NaN.

Code:

```
if (df.loc[df['sr'] == 1]['sma'].values[0] != 'NaN') or (df.loc[df['sr'] == 1]['sma'].values[0] != "nan"):
    print(df.loc[df['sr'] == 1]['sma'].values[0])
```

> There should be no output, but it is printing **nan**

Comment: The `NaN` object is not the same as the `"nan"` string

Comment: Post the output of `df.to_dict()` in your question

Comment: you have an 'OR' in your if statement. So it will get into the loop. I don't think this is a good way to check. You are checking for a string. Are you sure you want to check for a string `NaN` ?

Comment: `if df.loc[df['sr'] == 1]['sma'].notna().values[0]: ...`